# How to resolve type mismatch signed to unsigned in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In this below code snippet, how to convert signed integer to unsigned integer without implicit conversion.

```
- (NSUInteger) getSysInfo: (uint) typeSpecifier
  {
      size_t size = sizeof(int);
      int results;
      int mib[2] = {CTL_HW, typeSpecifier};
      sysctl(mib, 2, &results, &size, NULL, 0);
      return (NSUInteger) results;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just declare `results` as `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int value = 1234;
unsigned int unsigned_value = (unsigned int) value;
```